# UIPickerVIew cells show dark background

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView which I can't get to show correctly. The background of the cells in the picker shows a dark shade or completely black, depending on the transparency (alpha channel) set on the picker (See images below). The first image shows an alpha of 1, and the second one shows it at 0.7. Delegate and data source are set, as the second image shows. I am not returning custom views for the cells, just returning a title. Also setting the alpha to 0 will not work because the background is invisible, but so is the entire picker.

Anyone experienced this before? Thanks

[image: UIPickerView with alpha set to 1.0]

[image: UIPickerView with alpha set to 0.7]

Comment: How did you implement/instantiate the UIPickerView?

Comment: It is created in IB. All UI elements in my app are contained in a storyboard.

Comment: Are you implementing delegate source of uipickerview? What is the background color in your IB? Are you sure you're not setting any color through  code?

Comment: Source and delegate are implemented correctly, the data is loading. I've tried different background colours; Black, white, fully transparent. That has some effect but I still have this dark tint.

Comment: Get the count of subviews: [[pickerView subviews] count]
Then try to hide one a one until you find out which view is messing with you:
[[[pickerView subviews] objectAtIndex:x] setHidden:YES]